# Como calcular a média para grupos e identificar o valor máximo?

Tags: python, pandas

Tenho uma planilha onde preciso achar o mês com maior média de vendas.

Com o código abaixo eu consegui, mas quando imprimo o objeto aparece todas as informações desordenadas como pode ser visto na imagem.

https://prnt.sc/xka518

Eu preciso Imprimir o mês com o maior valor faturado para todos os funcionários (exemplo: “Agosto de 2020 - Total Faturado: 15.000”

O código que estou usando.

```
dfseason = df.groupby(by='Month')['Billed'].sum().nlargest(1)
print(dfseason)
```

Quando imprimo o objeto tenho as informações como na imagem

https://prnt.sc/xka7uw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma forma de retornar os valores de forma "ordenada" é utilizar o reset_index

```
dfseason = df.groupby(by='Month', sort=True)['Billed'].sum().nlargest(1).reset_index()
dfseason
```

Saída

```
    Month   Billed
0   May     918
```

Para customizar uma frase

```
print(f"Mês {dfseason.loc[0,'Month']} - Total faturado {dfseason.loc[0,'Billed']}")
```

Saída

```
Mês May - Total faturado 918
```

Answer (score 4):

Se eu entendi o que você precisa, é possível resolver usando o método `agg`:

```py
tab =df.groupby(by='Month').agg({'Billed':'sum'})
#ordenando a tabela
tab=tab.sort_values('Billed',ascending=False)
tab
```

Retorna:

```
       Billed
Month        
May       918
Nov       885
Apr       735
Dec       694
Jul       634
Jun       542
Sep       539
Aug       438
```

O valor máimo, portanto, é obtido por `tab.iloc[0,:]`.

**Imprimindo os resultados formatados:**

```py
for k, v in tab.to_dict()['Billed'].items():
    print("{} 2020 - Total Billed {}".format(k,v))
```

Retorna:

```
May 2020 - Total Billed 918
Nov 2020 - Total Billed 885
Apr 2020 - Total Billed 735
Dec 2020 - Total Billed 694
Jul 2020 - Total Billed 634
Jun 2020 - Total Billed 542
Sep 2020 - Total Billed 539
Aug 2020 - Total Billed 438
```

Para imprimir apenas o maior:

```py
print("{} 2020 - Total Billed {}".format(tab.index[0],tab.Billed[0]))
```

```
May 2020 - Total Billed 918
```

Comment: Usando seu método a saída sai exatamente igual a  minha.

Comment: Bom, então não entendi a pergunta. Qual o problema dessa saída? Como vc gostaria que ficasse?

Comment: Eu preciso manipular esse objeto e dar um print exemplo.
May 2020 - Total Billed : 918

Comment: Entendi agora. Vou editar a resposta

Comment: Está retornando oito valores iguais (já que são oito meses com valores). Seria possivel retornar apenas um valor?